# typescript: Abstract class parameter in constructor of class

Tags: typescript

I want to pass a class as parameter to the constructor of a class.

```
interface IFileHandler {
  getFiles (): string[]
}

class FileHandler implements IFileHandler
{
  getFiles ()
  {
    return ['hello', 'world'];
  }
}

class XmlToJson
{
  private FileHandler: IFileHandler;

  constructor (FileHandler: IFileHandler)
  {
    this.FileHandler = new FileHandler();
  }
}
```

How do you use the proper types for this? I need FileHandler to depend on an abstract class.

I get this error

```
This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'IFileHandler' has no construct signatures.
```

EDIT: as requested

```
interface IFileHandler {
  getFiles (): string[]
}

class DerivedExampleFileHandler implements IFileHandler
{
  getFiles ()
  {
    return ['hello', 'world'];
  }
}

class XmlToJson
{
  private _fileHandler: IFileHandler;

  constructor (DerivedExampleFileHandler: IFileHandler)
  {
    this._fileHandler = new DerivedExampleFileHandler();
  }
}
```

still the following error:

```
This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'IFileHandler' has no construct signatures.
```

Comment: Apparently, I don't really understand the point you want to achieve. Could you explain it more detailed?

Comment: @lukasl-dev updated example. I want the class (FileHandler) passed to the constructor of XmlToJson to depend on a non-concrete type to (partially) comply to SOLID.

Comment: Yes, can you please try to change the name of the object that is created inside the constructor? Like this:     this.FileHandler = new DerivatedExampleFileHandler(); and also the declaration of that class. That class has the same name with the XmlToJson classes property/variable.

Comment: @FatihErsoy that probably works if I remove the constructor parameter altogether and directly import DerivedExampleFileHandler() but this would mean the FileHandler implementation would not be interchangable. I need to fully decoupled, later I will try adding Dependency Injection.

Comment: @stackcen It seems it has nothing with names (my suspections were not true) as Oleksii's answer points out but you are trying to create the object again. I posted an answer and updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with naming, interfaces just don't have constructor signature, you can find more info [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&e=83#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDFgBsIAk4gAmOUyA3gLABQyyA5hGJjgM7IAUAlAFzIthRQdANoBdagF9q1UJFiIUzPAWLQAwgHsQ-KAFcEYctVq0QEAO5deGbMqIlJ0qgixwWbJfnvRkwALYADjh+EOBsNjheqlDUlDT0jEpsXMZG8bRQjLpQIMjCAOQAFhBYWBr5ADTI+eYaUFiE+aIA3KlSVO3ULm5sABp+WAAqGgBSLFqxqQGCAG5wkMieKiTWS95QrVSpCFo6+mB1HGvRvMckmtoC+5ypcSbIYIXALAB0Zz4AvMhm5ou2USQuJtaO1Os5doYEMgvj9kP0hqNxiB2O8oJwgA)
So what you need to do is to define an interface with constructor signature:

```
interface IFileHandler {
  getFiles (): string[]
}

interface FileHandlerConstruct {
    new(): IFileHandler
}

class FileHandler implements IFileHandler
{
  getFiles ()
  {
    return ['hello', 'world'];
  }
}

class XmlToJson
{
  private FileHandler: IFileHandler;

  constructor (FileHandler: FileHandlerConstruct)
  {
    this.FileHandler = new FileHandler();
  }
}

const c = new XmlToJson(FileHandler)
```

A [link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&e=83#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDFgBsIAk4gAmOUyA3gLABQyyA5hGJjgM7IAUAlAFzIthRQdANoBdagF9q1UJFiIUzPAWLQAwgHsQ-KAFcEYctVq0QEAO5deGbMqIlJ0qgixwWbJfnvRkwALYADjh+EOBsNjheqlDUlDT0jEpsXMZG8bRQjLpQIMjCAOQAFhBYWBr5ADTI+eYaUFiE+aIA3KlSVO3ULm5sABp+WAAqGgBSLFqxqQGCAG5wkMieKiTWS95QrVSpCFo6+mB1HGvRvMckmtoC+5ypcSbIYIXALAB0Zz4AvMhm5ou2USQuJtaO1Os5doYEMgvj9kP0hqNxiB2O8oJwgA)

Answer (score 0):

Rename the parameter in `XmlToJson`:

```
class XmlToJson
{
  private FileHandler: IFileHandler;

  constructor (Handler: IFileHandler)
  {
    this.FileHandler = new FileHandler();
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you have a name collision between the type `FileHandler` and the parameter name `FileHander`.

Comment: Unfortunately it ain't that, I double checked and it is correctly  instantiated as new FileHandler().

Comment: I updated my answer. This should remove your error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to employ dependency injection:

```
interface IFileHandler {
  getFiles (): string[]
}

class FileHandler implements IFileHandler
{
  getFiles ()
  {
    return ['hello', 'world'];
  }
}

class XmlToJson
{
  private FileHandler: IFileHandler;

  constructor (FileHandler: IFileHandler)
  {
    this.FileHandler = FileHandler;
  }

}
```

if you are going to employ object creation;

```
class XmlToJson
{
  private FileHandler: IFileHandler;

  constructor ()
  {
    this.FileHandler = new FileHandler();
  }

}
```

access the typescript link: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDFgBsIAk4gAmOUyA3gFDLIDmEYmOAzsgBQCUAXMk2FKDQDaAXQoBfChQRY4TFgBFowAG4RCjPAWLRkwALYAHHHojgWGbJqIkKlanQaWWHKuVfUo9AK5QQyQQDkABYQWFgA9gEANMgBAO7hUFiEAcIA3K4SElIycsgAGnpYACrhAFJM4SC2rgb8ynCQyBr41tDcFjit2lAZrghVvFBeCGCJbIr1ai1aJB0zbVDsrnbUyGBBwEwAdAs9yAC8yJMq05bdJBnU2dQDIJU4Gkwcq2vIdw8Q2xE0rBtbu3Os2g2wcTw47CuyGy2RwYGQAEdDsgQBA4sclKp1EDFhw%20nDkAAPZGo9GFErlSogVgIyEUQnbD7hR5OPFAA)

Also, there's a quickway to implement this in typescript:

```
class XmlToJson
{
  constructor (private fileHandler : IFileHandler)
  {}
}
```

access to second solution: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDFgBsIAk4gAmOUyA3gFDLIDmEYmOAzsgBQCUAXMk2FKDQDaAXQoBfChQRY4TFgBFowAG4RCAUQAecALYAHHIzwFi0ZMH04dEcCwzZjREhUrU6DByw5VyP6lHoAVygQZEEAcgALCCwsAHtwgBpkcIB3OKgsQnDhAG4fCQkpGTlkAA0dLAAVOIApJjiQFx8ERt4oQIQwDLY9fmU4SGQYB3wnM257HDHTKHYfMiLqVpAGw08OV2pkFbWIADp4mlYwSOAmfZHpkxJ99yMmDnZ86kLJHDBkAEdkAF5kEAQVLIRT9NRaXQGCBGGYkDj5D7ITR-AFA8qVGr1RqsL7PCiafa7OLrZjwihAA)